# signup_user() throws fatal error

Tags: user-registration, fatal-error, signup

When I use the [signup_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/signup_user/) function, Wordpress throws a fatal error.
I've allowed user registration in the settings, and was expecting it to work straight out of the box.
Has this function been deprecated?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! could you include the complete code for `signup_user`, how you use it?

Comment: It looks like that function only exists for the wp-signup.php file, which is accessed directly (like wp-login.php). I don't believe it's intended for use by themes and plugins. The documentation is automatically generated, so this isn't entirely clear.

Comment: no it has not been deprecated. Rather than asking how to fix `signup_user()` you should ask how to achieve the original goal ( `signup_user` is the wrong solution, don't ask how to fix your solution, ask how to solve your problem, you fell into the X Y Problem trap )